# ExtJS Nesting panels within border panels with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs

I accidentally deleted this post before, so I am resubmitting :\

I'm new to Ext JS and MVC in general and am toying with creating an app with a chart nested within a panel nested within a border panel within an app. [From top to bottom it goes Viewport > bordered panel > panel in 'center region' > chart]

The reason why I'm nesting a panel within the border panel is that the nested panel will hold both the chart as well as a toolbar for the chart, both of which are dynamic depending on the user's selection.

While simply having the border panel reference the externally defined chart view works well, once I try having it reference an externally defined panel view it throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined', and Aptana gives me a 'name is undefined' namespace error whether or not I have the nested panel reference the chart or simply be left empty. I have double checked my name spacing so I'm a little lost in where to start looking for the problem.

My base application file is as follows:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Chart',

    appFolder: 'chart',

    controllers:['sidebar.Navigation', 'commoditycontrol.Commoditycontrol',    
    'chart.oil.Spreads'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                region: 'north',
                xtype: 'commoditycontrol',
            }, {
                region: 'east',
                xtype: 'sidebarnavigation',
            }, {
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'oilbase',
            }]
        });
    },

});
```

The 'oilbase' view is simply a panel that imports the chart and chart toolbar view (in this case I've left the toolbar view out)

```
Ext.define('Chart.view.base.Oil', {
   extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
   alias: 'widget.oilbase',

   name: 'oilbase',
   layout: 'fit',

   items: [{
       xtype: 'oilspreads'
   }]

});
```

And here's the chart view 'oilspreads'

```
Ext.define('Chart.view.chart.oil.Spreads', {
   extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
   alias: 'widget.oilspreads',

   name: 'oilspreads',
   layout: 'fit',
   store: 'Chart.store.oil.Spreads',
   config: {
   style: {
            background: '#333333'
          },
    },

    axes: [
        {
            title: 'Close',
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['close'],
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
            cls: 'axis'
        },
        {
            title: 'Month',
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['month'],
            cls: 'axis'
        }
    ],

    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'close'
        }
    ]
});
```

Again, everything works fine if I reference the chart view in the application rather than the 'oilbase' empty panel. If I reference the default panel xtype, everything works as well.

Is nesting panels simply discouraged? My gut feeling is that I'm simply missing an obvious namespacing issue but I would appreciate a 2nd set of eyes, as well as comments as to my approach to the MVC pattern for ExtJs in general.

Thanks

Comment: Although you clearly spent the time to explain your problem, I'm still confused. Could you define "externally defined chart"; how do you reference the chart view; and what do you mean by the 'oilbase' empty panel? - It seems to me you do define an item for it. Is the code you have provided working fine?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for being unclear. By externally defined chart, I mean a chart view defined in another file besides the application (the 'oilspreads' view I pasted, the last code sample).

And by oilbase empty panel, I mean the panel that is bare except for referencing the oilspreads chart in its 'items'. 

The application works fine if I set the 'oilspreads' chart as an item of the application, or if I include 'oilbase' as an item of the application but do not set oilspreads as an item of oilbase. It only breaks if I set oilspreads as an item of oilbase

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by 'as an item of the application', so forgive me if the following is irrelevant: for the view to be loaded correctly it has to be defined either in the `views` config of your app, or in the `views` config of one of the controllers. Have you done that?

Comment: by 'item of the application' i mean the application renders the chart just fine when i reference the chart directly in the application file, i.e. items: [{ xtype: 'oilspreads' <-- the chart }] but it breaks if I instead do items: [{ xtype: 'oilbase' <-- an empty panel }] Here are some pictures to help illustrate. This is my structure that works: http://i.imgur.com/KkLtf.png    And this is my structure that fails: http://i.imgur.com/d0qmm.png  What do you mean the view config of my app? Do you have an example? I defined my view in my chart's controller to load chart data if thats what you mean

Comment: Those photos above are for the MVC structure of my app, not the physical layout, which I want to end up being like this: http://i.imgur.com/y1zLu.png Thansk again for your help so far

Comment: Okay, disregard everything, I figured it out. You were right, I did not define the view in the controller for oilbase, I didn't realize you needed to define a controller if you weren't calling a model or store, or if it wasn't accepting user input. Wow, i feel silly...Thanks again for your help

Comment: Just added an answer to wrap things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the view to be loaded correctly it has to be defined either in the views config of your app, or in the views config of one of the controllers.